# How to clear a variable from within the subscribe method in Angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

I din't get proper answer on the internet. I may be asking wrong question. Here is my code:

```
filtersTree: any[];


if (...) {
  this.myService.myMethodOne().subscribe(data => {
    this.filtersTree = data;
    });
  }
else {
  this.myService.myMethodTwo().subscribe(data => {
    this.filtersTree = data.filters;
  });
}
```

See `data` inside subscribe. Every time this code is called the previous values stays there and the whole UI is flooded with stale values along with new values.

I want to clear it before the next call is made. Please help.

Comment: ... question is very unclear .. but I guess what You getting is following: in your `if` condition may change with time - hence you would have 2 time subscribing ... why not to check the condition inside rx pipeline/subscription, `this.myService.myMethodTwo().pip(...`, or see rxjs `iif`  ...

Comment: Don't focus on `if-else`. My primary problem is to have a fresh `data` when subscribing.

Comment: @Tanzeel Do you explain it more ?

Comment: @GRD, thanks for reaching out. I think I'm asking a wrong question. May be the requirement is not like this. I need to check with my tech lead once she is back on Monday. I'll update you.

Comment: @Tanzeel Okay. Update this on. Thank You.